# How do I do an EDA on boolean/binary data without ML?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, binary-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I'm looking to get some insight on what methods I can use to help identify key factors in my dataset that influence my dependent variable and how to prove that they are statically significant. There is about 15 columns and a couple thousand rows of data. I've included a small sample. All of the data is in binary. I'm not looking for any ML classification or regression models, only statistic-based methods. Also python is preferred.

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 3 | column 3 | Dependent variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Do you consider [multiple correspondence analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) to be ML?

Comment: Nope i think MCA would be okay to use. I'm just not sure how to.

Comment: This [chapter](https://personal.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-MCA2007-pretty.pdf) describes the math. For software there is a [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/mca/), and here is an [R code](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/114-mca-multiple-correspondence-analysis-in-r-essentials/#r-code) example.

Comment: Would MCA be useful in helping identify key independent variables or will it just help me understand the relationship between the variables?